# AWK process header and footer

Tags: awk

I am trying to use awk script to read student data. The file has few header lines and few footer lines. (assume first 3 and last 3)
Actual student data is placed in between header and footer separated by comma like below,

name,age,place

I wants to print the age of the student along with the header and footer.

**Sample data:**

```
Header 1
Header 2
Header 3
dhana,28,USA
subha,24,India
Footer 1
Footer 2
Footer 3
```

**Expected output:**

```
Header 1
Header 2
Header 3
28
24
Footer 1
Footer 2
Footer 3
```

**My code:**

```
BEGIN{ FS = ","}
{ 
    if(NR > 3)
    {
        print $2
    }else{
        print $0
    }
}
```

**My output:**

```
Header 1
Header 2
Header 3
28
24
```

I am skipping header using NR operator. how to print footer and process only the student data alone (age)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -F',' 'NF == 3{ $0 = $2 }1' file
```

The output:

```
Header 1
Header 2
Header 3
28
24
Footer 1
Footer 2
Footer 3
```

Answer (score 1):

a double scan algorithm will give you more control

```
$ awk -F, -v h=3 -v f=3 'NR==FNR {n=NR; next} 
                         FNR>h && FNR<=n-f {$0=$2}1' file{,}

Header 1
Header 2
Header 3
28
24
Footer 1
Footer 2
Footer 3
```

where `h` and `f` specifies header and footer lines to be skipped for processing.

Comment: I thought of using similar kind of logic. Is there any way to avoid double scanning and pass as argument using wc -l filename?

Comment: You can fully eliminate by delayed processing (keep the 'f` lines in buffer and not end of file process one), however not sure about the code complexity it will add.  Note that `wc` is also scanning the file, may not add any benefit.  You should time it first before trying to optimize though...